# What does if(!sequence.hardPaused) mean?

Tags: javascript

```
if(sequence.settings.autoPlay && !sequence.hardPaused) {
    $status.css({"opacity": 0}, 500).removeClass("active");
}
```

What does `!` signify?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FLogical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is [Logical NOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation)

```
!sequence.hardPaused  means
```

reversing the   boolean value of

`sequence.hardPaused`

if `sequence.hardPaused` is true   `!sequence.hardPaused` will be `false`.

Comment: @Baadshah maybe because the link you posted is for PHP? (I'm not the downvoter btw)

Comment: @basilikum Thanks for the spot baslikum.